# Adding 'CRM' features to a Django website

Tags: python, django, crm

I'm building a website in Django. I want each user of the site to have some basic client management tools - add a client and contact information, add certain events around the clients, text/email clients, etc.

The CRM feature will be an important feature for the site members, but the overall site is a community and not a CRM platform, so I'm not really loooking to build on sugarCRM or similar.

My question, are there any Django or python packages that I could plugin that would add CRM tools? Or should I just roll my own? If so, any design pattern resources out there I could follow? Another option I'm looking into is integrating with a web service like SalesForce api, but I'm not sure if its overkill or costly.

Comment: Did you search at all before you asked this?  http://code.google.com/p/django-crm/

Comment: Yes, django-crm is the only one I found and am trying to setup and play with it. Have you used it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`django-addressbook`](https://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-addressbook/wiki/Home) or [`django-crm`](http://code.google.com/p/django-crm/source/checkout) might be good starting points. If you come up with something great, open source it :)

Comment: Thanks for django-addressbook. Will check it out.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry if this comes across as a plug, but I wanted to add that if you're looking to integrate a Django site with the Salesforce service, I've written a tool that allows you to treat your Salesforce instance as a DB, accessible through the Django ORM.

http://github.com/freelancersunion/django-salesforce

We're using it at the Freelancers Union for various CRM integrations, so it's in active use an maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking. At the moment testing out http://www.koalix.org - it has some basic CRM features as well as accounting and products. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

look at all new django crm in github. you can strip down as per your need.

https://github.com/MicroPyramid/Django-CRM